# Any good csv bash utility?

Tags: command-line, csv, software-rec

I'm currently working with some CSV datasets and was wondering whether there are any good (even better if standard) CLI ways of manipulating CSV data.

To be more precise, I mainly want to be able to:

- vertically concatenate CSVs
- SQL-style join CSVs on one or more columns

Comment: @Kusalananda, though see `info gawk fpat` for some way for `gawk` to handle a little more complex csvs.

Answer (score 12):

Yes: CSVkit. http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/

CSV is not a standard that has anything to do with Unix, hence there are no "standard" (as in POSIX) utility for working with CSV files.

To vertically concatenate CSV files, use something like `paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv` (unless the CSV data contains newlines).  CSVKit will handle most other kinds of operations (including queries and database loading, re-formatting etc.) on CSV files.

CSVKit is a collection of Python utilities. Among these is `csvjoin`, for example.

Comment: Note that `ksh93` has built-in support to process csvs (not all flavours though).

Comment: What about vertically concatenating columns within the same file?

Comment: @ptrcao That sounds like something you could do with a combination of `cut` and `paste`, but feel free to ask a new question about this.

Comment: `cut` and `paste` are just shell commands or a part of CSVkit?

Comment: @ptrcao These are standard shell tools. As I don't know what your data is, I suggested using these.  There is also a `csvcut` tool in CSVkit, and `csvstack`, but again I know nothing about your data and what it is you want to do. I suggest that you ask a brand new question about this rather than using the comment thread of other questions.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have done as you advised: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558347/concatenating-columns-of-the-same-csv-file-to-create-a-new-column-with-a-new-hea