# Concatenating columns of the same csv file to create a new column with a new heading

Tags: awk, sed, csv, csvkit

What I have is a CSV file to this effect:

```
+------------+--------------+
| Category I | Sub-Category |
+------------+--------------+
|       1144 |          128 |
|       1144 |          128 |
|       1000 |          100 |
|       1001 |          100 |
|       1002 |          100 |
|       1002 |          100 |
|       1011 |          102 |
|       1011 |          102 |
|       1011 |          102 |
|       1011 |          102 |
|       1011 |          102 |
|       1011 |          102 |
|       1013 |          103 |
|       1013 |          103 |
|       1013 |          103 |
|       1013 |          103 |
|       1013 |          103 |
|       1013 |          103 |
|       1013 |          103 |
+------------+--------------+
```

I wish to concatenate the first and second columns above to form a third, new column with a new arbitrary heading, to this effect:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| Category ID | Sub-Category | Arbitrary New Heading |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|        1144 |          128 |               1144128 |
|        1144 |          128 |               1144128 |
|        1000 |          100 |               1000100 |
|        1001 |          100 |               1001100 |
|        1002 |          100 |               1002100 |
|        1002 |          100 |               1002100 |
|        1011 |          102 |               1011102 |
|        1011 |          102 |               1011102 |
|        1011 |          102 |               1011102 |
|        1011 |          102 |               1011102 |
|        1011 |          102 |               1011102 |
|        1011 |          102 |               1011102 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
|        1013 |          103 |               1013103 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

My usual go-to utility, csvkit does not have the means to achieve this, afaik - see https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/issues/930.

What is a simple solution not requiring advanced programming knowledge, which can achieve this?

I'm vaguely aware of awk and sed as potential solutions, but I don't want to limit the enquiry to those just in case there is a better (i.e. simpler) solution.

The solution must be efficient for very large files, i.e containing 120,000+ lines.

Edit: I have included the sample data for the convenience of those wanting to take a crack at it; download here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/achtyxg7qi1629k/category-subcat-test.csv?dl=0

Comment: (1) Please post sample data (as text) in your question. (2) If your input file is CSV, show it as such. (3) If you want CSV output, say so (in the question, in an English sentence) and show it as such. (4) Specify (in an English sentence) how you want the first row (i.e., the headers) handled.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  (1) I already have linked the entire text file above , (2) I've mentioned CSV in many places, the file extension is CSV, the question tag is CSV, CSV is in the title.  (3) I suppose I could explicitly say csv output, but the parsiminous interpretation is that since I didn't ask for change in file, there's no reason to think that's what I wanted (4) in the original post, I mentioned "a third third, new column with a new arbitrary heading".  I'm not perfect, and there's room for improvement with anyone, but I felt it was generally clear is at stands.

Comment: @steeldriver @ G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica' I have converted the images to text now - please kindly reverse the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and this example input file

```
Category ID,Sub-Category
1001,128
1002,127
1002,126
1004,122
```

and running

```
mlr --csv put -S '$fieldName=${Category ID}." ".${Sub-Category}' input.csv >output.csv
```

you will have

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| Category ID | Sub-Category | fieldName |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| 1001        | 128          | 1001 128  |
| 1002        | 127          | 1002 127  |
| 1002        | 126          | 1002 126  |
| 1004        | 122          | 1004 122  |
+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

And you could run also csvsql, it works, in this way

```
csvsql -I --query 'select *,("Category ID" || " " || "Sub-Category") fieldname from input' input.csv >output.csv
```

Comment: With your `csvsql` solution, I got: [root@server test]# csvsql -I --query 'select *,("Category ID" || " " || "Sub-Category") fieldname from input' category-subcat-test.csv >output.csv
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: input
[SQL: select *,("Category ID" || " " || "Sub-Category") fieldname from input]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Comment: Rename please `category-subcat-test.csv` in input.csv and test again. If it works, you must change the query because you must insert your file name in the query. The name of mine is `input.csv`

Comment: I had it as such: `csvsql -I --query 'select *,("Category ID" || " " || "Sub-Category") fieldname from input' category-subcat-test.csv >output.csv`

Comment: ok, you must change the command in `csvsql -I --query 'select *,("Category ID" || " " || "Sub-Category") fieldname from "category-subcat-test"' category-subcat-test.csv >output.csv`

Comment: Thank you, that worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
Tried with below command

awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2,$1$2 }' file| sed '1i Category Sub-Category New Heading'
```

output

```
Category Sub-Category New Heading
1144 128 1144128
1144 128 1144128
1000 100 1000100
1001 100 1001100
1002 100 1002100
1002 100 1002100
1011 102 1011102
1011 102 1011102
1011 102 1011102
1011 102 1011102
1011 102 1011102
1011 102 1011102
1013 103 1013103
1013 103 1013103
1013 103 1013103
1013 103 1013103
1013 103 1013103
1013 103 1013103
```

Comment: Can you please make it output to a csv file, and confirm that all the columns are properly delimited?  We should be seeing headings also aligning properly with the data columns.